# Проблема c JavaFx приложением при компиляции

Tags: java, javafx, eclipse, fxml

[image: Скрин проблемы]

Не находит почему-то, пожалуйста помогите какой именно путь указать, всё перепробовал, заранее спасибо, но: Group root = new Group(); // Компилится

Comment: а если перед добавить `..`?

Comment: Всё равно не получается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По идее fxml разметка это ресурс и лежать этому файлу стоит в папке ресурсов

src/resources

далее вы вызываете

```
FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResources("путь к файлу относительно папки resources"))
```

getClass().getClassLoader().getResources() - благодаря этому вызову неважно из какого класса вы ищите ресурсы, т.е. неважна вложенность пакетов.

и лучше выкладывать код текстом, дополнив его скриншотом по необходимости.

Comment: Не получается, вот что прописал

Comment: 'Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("res/AdressBookInGUI.fxml"));'

Comment: я правильно понял, что теперь у вас fxml лежит src/resources/res/AdressBookInGUI.fxm‌​l ?

Comment: Я пишу на Eclipse

Comment: Я должен создать две папки в файловой системе где лежат src?

Comment: То есть resources/res  и туда их положить?

Answer (score 0):

Я решил проблему, слушайте те кто юзает JavaFX - Если у вас в *.fxml не правильно прописаны контроллеры то даже если вы правильно положите эти файлики и правильно пропишите строку FXMLloader, то программа просто вылетит, используйте для тестирования этой строки 
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("*.fxml"));
 какой нибудь fxml файл сгенерированный где-нибудь по умолчанию(без зависимостей)